# Absolute-positioned div doesn't stretch all the way down the body

Tags: html, css

I’m most probably forgetting something fundamental, but anyway.

What I’m trying to achieve is a blurred background. Although you’ll find a navigation, it’s not immediately visible and will be displayed upon clicking on the navigation icon taking the whole viewport while blurring the background. This part is ok. All the relevant content in the page is a simple contact form. I can’t place the form inside `<div id="in-blur"></div>` or it’s going to be blurred as well, therefore it doesn’t have any content, just holds the background image (to be blurred) itself. In order to place it behind the form I had to set `position: absolute` and establish `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%` for `#in-blur` since there is no content within. The problem: as I understand, `<body>` gets its height from `<main>` (where the contact form is) and although the height of `#in-blur` is set to 100% (of the body), the actual element is only going as far as the viewport. Ex.: if I check the page in landscape orientation and the viewport is 320px tall (as an iPhone 5S, for instance), the background image, that is, the #in-blur, ends at 320px leaving part of the form that needs scrolling without the background image. If I increase the height above 100% the background increases filling the empty space until the end, but I guess I wasn’t supposed to do so considering that I already have height set to 100% of the containing element, `<body>`, and `<body>` itself covers the whole page. Have I forgotten anything particular about absolute positioned elements?

I have the following HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="main-nav">

<div id="menu-close">
    <div id="menu-close-1"></div>
    <div id="menu-close-2"></div>
</div>

<nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Обо мне</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Метод</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Контакты</a></li> <!-- Replace with the PHP version accordingly -->
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="menu-wrapper">
    <div id="menu-icon-1"></div>
    <div id="menu-icon-2"></div>
    <div id="menu-icon-3"></div>
</div> 

<main class="margin-normal" id="contact-form">
    <section id="unique">
        <h1>контакты</h1> 
        <form action="#" name="form" autocomplete="on" method="post"> <!-- Check out PHP details and include the necessary info -->
            <fieldset>
                <label for="name">Имя<em>*</em></label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="45" aria-required>
                <label for="email">E-mail<em>*</em></label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
                <label for="subject">Тема<em>*</em></label>
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" aria-required>
                <label for="message">Сообщение<em>*</em></label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" aria-required></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Отправить">    
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </section>
</main>
</div>

<div id="in-blur"></div>

</body>
```

With this CSS for the relevant issue:

```
#in-blur
{
    background: url(../img/main_background.jpg) 50% 50% / cover no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    filter: blur(7px);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see if `position:fixed` on #in-blur solves your problem

Comment: `position: fixed` solved the initial problem and checking the implementation only in responsive dev tools of desktop browsers everything works, however, when debugging in the real mobile versions, probably due to resizing occurring when the browsers' navigation bar show up and hide while scrolling, the white trail that was static before because the background image was stretching now shows up for a second and the background resizes covering it. Weird effect. I'm still checking.

Answer (score 0):

the element with absolute position refers to its parent element which has its position set to relative(In your case that is 'html')

add this to your CSS, maybe it will solve the problem

```
html,body{
    min-height:100%;
}
```